# Filling secureObject array with VSTS variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have defined few variables as secret in the pipeline variables but when I try to use those by overriding the parameters file values with:

```
-secretsObject {"secrets":[{"secretName":"userpwd","secretValue":$(userpwd)}]}
```

I get "The provided value for the template parameter 'secretsObject' at line '1' and column '787' is not valid.'"

How should I pass the variables into the secrectObjects array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem lies within the use of double quotes. I got it working with following example:
$(appId) ="a12b34cd-ab12-1ab2-ab1c-a12bc-34de56" -> no double quotes
$(password) = bestpassword -> use double quotes

Example override:

```
{"secrets":[{"secretName":"AppID","secretValue":$(appId)},{"secretName":"password","secretValue":"$(password)"}]}
```